# MOD_REWRITE for URL variables, removing empty parameters and using more than 1field for the first and second variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I have a previous question that was answered very well but requires an amendment and I was unable to reply so have created a new question.

I required a mod_rewrite that made the following:

```
www.example.com?page=var1&cat=var2&subcat=var3&subsubcat=var4
```

into this:

```
www.example.com/var1/var2/var3/var4/
```

but that also covered the optional use of var2, var3 and var4 so if those variables were empty, it would still work.

The question was answered very well but it requires an amendment to work with different field options for var2, var3 and var4.

The code I have is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^page= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^page= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /?page=$1&cat=$2 [L]

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^page= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?page=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3 [L]

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^page= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?page=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3&subsubcat=$4 [L]
```

This works but I need it to be able to make an if-or-else for the choice of what field is being used for what variable and to tell the difference.

For example, if we have the following two strings normally, it is easy to distinguish what field goes for what variable:

```
www.example.com?page=var1&cat=var2&subcat=var3&subsubcat=var4

www.example.com?othervar1=var1&othervar2=var2&othervar3=var3&othervar4=var4
```

but for this string, it requires the ability to distinguish what field the variable is for:

```
www.example.com/var1/var2/var3/var4/
```

I need the mod_rewrite to choose which is being used.

As well as this, when I actually go to a folder that does exist, it does work correctly. For example, if I go to a folder called "test", which is an actual folder:

```
www.example.com/test/
```

it uses it as a variable for the "page" field. If I use the following without the end forward slash:

```
www.example.com/test
```

it outputs the following into the URL:

```
www.example.com/test/?page=test
```

I need it to work for folders that exist as normal also.

Please can someone tell me how this can be done? I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Also, can someone tell me what the "-MultiViews" bit means at the beginning as I have not come across this before?

Thank you.

Comment: You would need an URL structure like `www.example.com/value1/cat/value2/subcat/value3/subcat/value4/` if you want to be able to, e.g., omit `cat` but still have two `subcat`s. Similarly with other variables. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK first the **MultiViews** options: As per Apache manual:

#### [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html)

```
Content negotiated "MultiViews" are allowed using mod_negotiation.
```

In short if you have a file called `foo.html` and if browser requests `http://example.com/foo` then Apache automatically finds and appends extension and serves `foo.html` to browser rather than throwing **404**. This behavior causes many Rewrite rules to fail hence I disabled it at the start in my answer to your previous question.

Now to exclude real directories from being handled by rewrite rules we'll need an additional condition like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

#### To support multiple pretty URL schemes:

You have few options here. Please tell me which one you would like to have and I will provide rules for that.

**Option 1:** Have both `var name` and `var value` in your URL like this:

`www.example.com/page/var1/cat/var2/subcat/var3/subsubcat/var4` OR
`www.example.com/othervar1/var1/othervar2/var2/othervar3/var3/othervar4/var4`

This one gives you maximum flexibility and is very easy to handle in Rewrite rules if you are willing to go to this route. For this option Rewrite rules will need to be written only once and you will be fine for future changes as long # of variables don't change

**Option 2:** Have a difference **start** for each scheme. For ex:

`www.example.com/handler1/var1/var2/var3/var4` OR
`www.example.com/handler2/var1/var2/var3/var4`

This one is gives you shorter URL but doesn't provide flexibility like previous option. But this one is also very easy to handle in Rewrite rules. However for this option Rewrite rules will need to be written for every combination

So I would recommend **option 1** and would be happy to prepare a .htaccess for you if you like this option too.

### .htaccess file for option 2

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# 404 handler
ErrorDocument 404 /notFound.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^handler1/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^handler1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&cat=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^handler1/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?page=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^handler1/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?page=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3subsubcat=$4 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^handler2/([^/]+)/?$ /?othervar1=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^handler2/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?othervar1=$1&othervar2=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^handler2/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?othervar1=$1&othervar2=$2&othervar3=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^handler2/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?othervar1=$1&othervar2=$2&othervar3=$3othervar4=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
```

### .htaccess file for option 1

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# 404 handler
ErrorDocument 404 /notFound.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ $3?$1=$2 [N,QSA,DPI]
RewriteRule ^(/[^/]+|[^/]+/|/?)$ /index.php [L,QSA,DPI]
```

Using these rules a URL of `http://localhost/n1/v1/n2/v2/n3/v3/n4/v4` will be INTERNALLY redirected to `http://localhost/?n4=v4&n3=v3&n2=v2&n1=v1` treating each pair of URL segments separated by `/` as a `name-value` pair for QUERY_STRING. **BUT** keep in mind if URI doesn't have even number of segments eg: `http://localhost/n1/v1/n2/` then it will be redirected to `http://localhost/?n1=v1`, discarding extra n2.

Comment: @anubhava. Thank you for your reply. I would prefer to use the Option 2 for my current project but I am sure I and many others reading in future would require Option 1 also. If you could provide the Option 2 for me and, if you can, the Option 1 for other viewers and I may use it myself on another project. Also, I thought" Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews" went before "RewriteEngine on". Does it always go after or is it just for this version? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` can go before OR after `RewriteEngine on` I believe. Okay I will provide you .htaccess rules for both options in short while.

Comment: @anubhava. Please make sure if an error occurs, such as a 404, it is able to still go to the directed page e.g. ErrorDocument 404 /404.php. Thank you once again.

Comment: Sorry got caught up with some urgent work. I have provided .htaccess for option 2 above. Please try it and let me know. I will also provide you .htaccess rule for option 1 tonight.

Comment: @anubhava. I'm quite new to this site. Where will you put up the new .htaccess codes? Will you just amend the answer above or will it go somewhere else? Thank you.

Comment: Yes I will append the new code in my previous answer. At present you need to take the code under **.htaccess file for option 2** heading above to try it.

Comment: Sorry it look little longer. I have provided you rules for both the options.