# Multiple clean URL parameters, not in order

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm currently working on an advance search feature that needs to work with .htaccess clean urls. This search could have 3-5 Parameters depending on what the user inputs. So basically the search string ( before clean URL ) could be something like this:

```
http://www.example.com?category=lorem&subcategory=ipsum&on_sale=1&featured=1&vendor=foo
```

These parameters could also be in a different order, so I can't use the standard regex method to clean up the URL.

Comment: show me please example of correctly link.

Comment: I would want the url to look something like:
http://www.example.com/lorem/ipsum/1/1/foo
or
http://www.example.com/category/lorem/subcategory/ipsum/on_sale/1/featured/1/vendor/foo

Comment: or if there's another way, I'm open to opinons

Comment: order to rewrite must be constant, one parameter can be empty?

Comment: Yes so the most basic search could be example.com?on_sale=1. Something really obscure.

Comment: or that: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776208/mod-rewrite-for-url-variables-removing-empty-parameters-and-using-more-than-1fi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776208/mod-rewrite-for-url-variables-removing-empty-parameters-and-using-more-than-1fi).

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to use keywords & terms in the URL.

My final URL looked like so:

```
http://www.example.com/search/term/lorem/category/shirts/subcategory/tank-top/color/red/featured/1
```

In htaccess I looked for the signifier "/search" and made rules for search parameters that followed.

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ http://www.example.com/?page=search&keywords[]=$1&terms[]=$2 [QSA,NC]
```

etc,etc.

So basically in PHP, all odd indices are stored in a $keywords array and all even indices are stored in a $terms array.

I then check all keywords against a list of acceptable keywords to prevent MySQL injection.

```
$allowable_keywords = array('term','category','subcategory','color','featured');
```

I am then able to filter the search results with this tidy little search array by combining the keywords and terms.

```
$params = array_combine($keywords,$terms);

$params = array(
      'term'        => 'lorem',
      'category'    => 'shirts',
      'subcategory' => 'tank-top',
      'color'       => 'red',
      'featured'    =>  1 
);
```

Hope this helps!